# Install Facebook App with Custom Tab in pages with less than 2000 fans

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to workaround the restrictions of Facebook that doesn't allow me to install an app with a custom tab in a Facebook page with less than 2000 likes? I need to install the App to just test it and I don't have a page with more then 2000 likes.
The app is already released and someone is using it, but I need to upgrade it since on July 22nd the version 2.9 of the graph api will be deprecated. What should I do?

When I try to install the app in a page where I'm the Admin (I'm the Admin for the app as well) I receve the error:

> This page does not have permission to install custom tab

Please, has someone a solution that could help me?

Answer (score -1):

Since a custom tab is literally just a website you can simply test it by opening it directly instead of iframed on fb dot com.

Other than that you cannot test it with real pages unless that page has more than 2000 followers of course.